# How can i launch a modal after clicking each bar in Bar chart in Chartjs and also how can i get its data?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So im creating charts in javascript using **chartjs** , i have a problem that how can i select each bar in bar chart and launch a modal with its data.

I already tried the onClick event after options , but i think i have a wrong pattern. I dont know much more about chartjs and i think i need help. Here's my code :

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: outlet,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Players",
                    data: total_outlet,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "#f38b4a",
                        "#56d798",
                        "#ff8397",
                        "#6970d5",
                        "#ff0000",
                        "#339966",
                        "#004d00",
                        "#003366",
                        "#e62e00",
                        "#666633",
                        "#996633"
                    ],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                        "#f38b4a",
                        "#56d798",
                        "#ff8397",
                        "#6970d5",
                        "#ff0000",
                        "#339966",
                        "#004d00",
                        "#003366",
                        "#e62e00",
                        "#666633",
                        "#996633"
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                           min: 0,
                           fontColor: "white"
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                            display:false
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes:[{
                        ticks: {
                        fontColor: "white"
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                            display:false
                        }
                    }]
                },

                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Top 10 Outlet with Active UGL Terminals',
                    fontColor: "white"
                },
                legend: {
                    display:false,
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: "white"

                    }
                }



            }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite straightforward and is [documented at the Chart.js API page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementatevente). Below is a working snippet adapted from the official example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

let myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 2, 4, 8]
    }]
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var firstPoint = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt)[0];
  if (firstPoint) {
    var label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
    var value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];

    alert('Label: ' + label + "\nValue: " + value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```